# zclip not working with ajax loaded content

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, zclip

I have a wordpress site. I want to add a copy to clipboard button in all post in a listing. In post, the copy to clipboard is included in ajax loaded content. Zclip is working fine in normal content, not in ajax content.

Comment: I used the zclip function in the callback method of jQuery load function. It works now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example code

```
jQuery('.ajax_area').load('ajax_test_file.php', function() {
                jQuery('a.copy-description').zclip({
                path: '<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
                copy: function() {
                    return jQuery(this).find('p.description:first').text();
                }
            });
}
```